# Xenial 16.04: D-Link DWA-182 [aka "Wireless AC1200 Dual Band USB Adapter"] issues

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, 16.04, d-link

Reply to @matpauranoo -

Ok, did that, now it's recognised -

```
~$ iwconfig
enxc0a0bbe29477  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"dlink-5GHz-92DE"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 78:54:2E:4D:92:DE   
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=75/100  Signal level=57/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

~$ sudo lshw
*-usb:0
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: D-Link Wireless Adapter
                      vendor: Realtek
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@1:1.3
                      version: 0.00
                      serial: 123456
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=rtl8812au maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

Bit it only half works. The 2.4GHz/100mb band works, though slower than on board wireless, but 5GHz/1000mb does not.

===

**Original question -**

This is what I have, it's a gigabit wireless ethernet USB stick -

http://us.dlink.com/products/connect...d-usb-adapter/

It's history is as follows -

- 14.04 - working fine using this driver https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
- Upgrade to 15.04 - broken, driver no longer working. Same with 15.10 - I assumed due to changes with systemd or something. Gave up trying.
- Ran 16.04 LiveCD, plugged it in, instantly recognized, worked within seconds using only native Ubuntu. Heart fluttered with joy.
- Intalled 16.04 - broken again

lsusb shows -

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp.
```

Which is the correct identity for the device.

Now I don't want to install the rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux driver as I suspect it will have same problem as I had with 15.0x. Has anyone played with this device on 16.04 and can they offer any advice? Why did it work live, but not on install? That is the big question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the proprietary driver that you can find in
"Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers".
It is the dkms version of rtl8812au.
It works for me on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: In addition to above edit - I found it was necessary to disable 'secure boot' in BIOS to get device access. Why? No idea, no explanation in fora that suggested it as fix.