# Having trouble installing Dlink dwa-182 ac1200 wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Running Ubuntu 16.04, the WiFi adapter (a Dlink dwa-182 ac1200) is usually plug and play on Windows 10 (though it also has drivers) but since I switched to Ubuntu, it is not responding and I can't seem to be able to install the drivers.

I have never used Linux before. What do I have to do to install the drivers or otherwise get it working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

After the commands are computed and completed, do "plug out - plug in" your Dlink DWA-182.
Then check in the settings in wifi section and wait for a second tab to appear. Tabs can be seen in the image.

[image: tabs can be seen in the image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same USB wireless card. Running 18.04. No success with the above, but I had no trouble getting the card to work using the official D-Link linux driver. You can find the driver here:

http://support.dlink.ca/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182

Be sure you confirm that you have the right product and hardware release code.

After downloading the .zip file from D-link, I simply ran the install.sh script that D-link included, restarted and everything is up and running.

To run the script, extract the files from D-link, and find the intall.sh script. Then in terminal navigate to the folder containing the script, then:

```
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

This is also helpful if the machine doesn't have a current internet connection (not unlikely since you've just bought a usb wifi card) since you can load the D-link files on a usb stick or whatever.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Discussion in [Xenial 16.04: D-Link DWA-182 [aka "Wireless AC1200 Dual Band USB Adapter"] issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764744/xenial-16-04-d-link-dwa-182-aka-wireless-ac1200-dual-band-usb-adapter-issue)
The answer suggested "Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers" update, that did not work for me.

What did work on 16.04 was to bring on the USB stick the directory with the driver code from https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
Then "sudo make; make install" followed by a reboot.
Was already running without "Secure" BIOS

If you already have connectivity, like through a wired link, the driver in the official Xenial repo.

Answer (score 0):

## Setup Wireless USB dlink dwa-182 On Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 thru 20.04

Make sure USB wireless device not inserted

1. Update the system:
   `sudo apt update`
2. Install required packages:
   `sudo apt install git && build-essential`
3. Download the driver:
   `sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au`
4. Go to the directory:
   `cd rtl8812au`
5. Do the next commands consecutively:
   `sudo make clean`
   `sudo make`
   `sudo make uninstall`
   `sudo make install`

Reboot and insert USB wireless stick

-Persists reboots
-Works with dlink dwa-182 and linksys WUSB6300